# Validate password when signed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working on email authentication with `Devise`. The issue is not to validate password when signed up. Currently, users can sign up without password, just email. I want to avoid it.

**apps/views/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
    <div class="signForm">
      <p>Email</p>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
    </div>
    <div class="signForm">
      <p>Username</p>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="signForm">
      <p>Password</p>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", placeholder: "***********" %>
    </div>
    <div class="signForm">
      <p>Confirmation Password</p>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", placeholder: "***********" %>
    </div>
    <div class="signForm">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    </div>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks',
  confirmations: 'confirmations',
  registrations: 'registrations'
}
```

**apps/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb**

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?

      sign_in(resource)

      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

**apps/controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  def account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding `password_required` in your model...

```
protected

def password_required?
  confirmed? ? super : false
end
```

[reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed after adding `validatable`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :validatable
```